# dynamicaly add menu to website.layout odoo

Tags: python, web, odoo

i am working on a website module and i want to add menus to the website.layout nav when the client login and it desepear when he logout 
i tried odoo cms but the menu will be there when the user logout 
i also tried this but it doesn't work too

```
<template id="test" inherit_id="website.layout">
  <t t-if="user_id">
     <xpath expr="//div[@class='collapse']/ul[@class='nav']" position="inside">
          <li>testMenu</li>
     </xpath>
 </t>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

i find the answer :) 
the answer is that i should nest using the id in the xpath like this

```
<template id="main_layout" inherit_id="website.layout">
        <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']//ul[@id='top_menu']/li[@class='divider']" position="before">
            <li t-ignore="true" t-if="website.user_id != user_id">
                <a href="/page/products">
                    <span>Products</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </xpath>
 </template>
```